# Minimum separation in compact metric spaces is preserved by homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Consider two compact metric spaces $(X_1,d_1)$ and $(X_2,d_2)$ equipped with their metric topologies $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$.

I would like to show that, given some homeomorphism $h:X\rightarrow Y$ and any nonzero distance $\delta_1$, there exists a nonzero constant $\delta_2$ such that, for any two elements $y, z \in X_1$, $d_1(x,y) > \delta_1$ implies $d_2(h(x),h(y)) > \delta_2$.

Such a statement is claimed, directly or indirectly, in a few papers (see [this one](https://home.csulb.edu//%7Escrass/teaching/math456/articles/devaney_defn_chaos.pdf), which claims it "easy to verify".)

*MY WORK SO FAR:*

My line of attack has been to construct a set $U$ consisting of every open ball of radius $\delta_1$ in $\tau_1$, each of which we can call $U^i$, which clearly covers $X_1$. By construction, any two elements of $X_1$, $y$ and $z$, separated by more than $\delta_1$ will lie in distinct $U^i$'s.

Since $h$ is a homeomorphism, the set "$h(U^i)$" (abusing notation a bit here) consists of disjoint open sets of $\tau_2$ which cover $X_2$, which are each an arbitrary union of open balls in $\tau_2$. Since $(X_2,d_2)$ is a compact metric space, we can take that underlying collection of open balls that make up "$h(U^i)$" and find a finite subset of it that still covers $X_2$, which we can call $V^i$.

This is where I'm stuck; ideally, I would like to show that the $V^i$ are disjoint, and that $h(y)$ and $h(z)$ are in distinct $V^i$; followed by a triangle inequality argument to show that a minimum distance between $h(y)$ and $h(z)$ exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's easier to work with sequences: Assume that for some given $\delta_1 > 0$ there is no such $\delta_2 >0$. Then to each positive number $1/n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there are $x_n,y_n \in X$ such that $d_1(x_n,y_n) > \delta_1$ but
$d_2(h(x_n),h(y_n)) \le 1/n$. As $Y$ is compact there are subsequences $(x_{n_k})$ and $(y_{n_k})$ such that $(h(x_{n_k}))$ and $(h(y_{n_k}))$ are convergent to the same limit $z$, say. Since $h$ is a homeomorphism we have
$x_{n_k} \to h^{-1}(z)$  and $y_{n_k} \to h^{-1}(z)$ $(k \to \infty)$. Thus
$$
\delta_1 < d_1(x_{n_k},y_{n_k}) \to 0 \quad (k \to \infty),
$$
a contradiction.

Comment: I should have mentioned I was looking for a method that explicitly avoids sequences, but this is a perfectly good (and very elegant) answer!